# jsPDF Library - Numeric (only) Field

Tags: javascript, numbers, textfield, jspdf

Using jsPDF library, how can I create a numeric field?
I have not found anything in the documentation.
Can a javascript control be placed on that field?.[Image that better explains what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sxH8.png)

Comment: Ok, read what you wrote - "text field that accepts only numbers" - you need a field with type number not text. This might help, since I don't know the lib - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number